# how to get the grub menu to show when starting computer

Tags: boot, grub

elementary OS works but only when i go to advanced startup, i can access it from there. On startup, the grub menu doesn't appear - it goes straightaway to windows 10. is there a way to show the grub menu at startup? i have already tried using easy BCD.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Terminal put in: sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
2. Do this: `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 -> #GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`
3. This allows the the grub menu to be displayed and not hidden.
4. Save the file
5. In terminal put in: sudo update-grub

This might not work but is one of the most common reasons for grub to be hiding.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) and setup how you like easly. Just make some small changes like move up then down, remove something you don't need, save it and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UEFI, you might have to go into the BIOS and change the UEFI boot order. You should see three options, Windows, Elementary OS, and Linux. Set the first boot option to the Linux, second to Elementary OS and the third to Windows.